# In matlab, plot a heatmap and a line plot on the same figure

Tags: matlab

In matlab 2014b, I want to make a heatmap and then overlay a line plot using the right y-axis. For example

```
colormap bone
data = rand(6);
imagesc(data)
ax = gca; 
ax.XTick = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
ax.YTick = [1 2 3 4 5 6];

hold on
```

Now plot a line but use the right y-axis because this has negative values:

```
x2 = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
y2 = [-0.0001   -0.0997   -0.1997   -0.2995   -0.3994   -0.4995];
plot(x2,y2,'r')
```

Comment: How do you define the "right y-axis" ? I don't understand what you want to obtain, can you make a drawing ?

Comment: @Ratbert as in, on the right side of the plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it with a variation of [`plotyy`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) where the first plot is composed of `NaNs`.

Here is the code:

```
hold on

colormap bone
data = rand(6);
imagesc(data)
ax = gca; 
yT = ax.YTick;

x2 = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
y2 = [-0.0001   -0.0997   -0.1997   -0.2995   -0.3994   -0.4995];
[ax, ~, h] = plotyy(yT*NaN, yT, x2,y2);

ax(1).YLim = [yT(1)-0.5 yT(end)+0.5];
ax(1).YTick = yT;
ax(1).YColor = [0 0 0];
set(h, 'Color', 'r');
ax(2).YColor = [1 0 0];
ax(2).YTick = -0.5:0.1:0;
```

and the result:

[image]

Best,